# SwiftUI - How to change the background Color of top safe area to gray?

Tags: swiftui

I want to change the background color of top safe area from green to gray. I have looked everywhere but could not find any solution. The screen in preview looks like this.

[image]

My codes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name = ""
    init() {
            //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with Large Font
           UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
           UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .gray
        }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack{
                VStack{
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                        .frame(height:200)
                        .padding()
                        .background(backgrounImage())
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(Color.gray,lineWidth: 4))
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }.navigationTitle("Tanvir")
                .background(Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add another view on top of the `ZStack`:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) { // <- Don't forget this
                ,,,
 
                GeometryReader { reader in
                    Color.yellow
                        .frame(height: reader.safeAreaInsets.top, alignment: .top)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't forget the stack alignment!

[image]

## Consistant Bar for the entire App

If you need  it to be on all of your views, try putting the  code somewhere more consistent like where you are providing the `contentView`:

```
@main
struct SwiftUIAppPlaygroundApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                ContentView()

                GeometryReader { reader in
                    Color.yellow
                        .frame(height: reader.safeAreaInsets.top, alignment: .top)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working, but can I get a dynamic height of the Color View instead of giving approximate value?

Comment: Updated to use geometry reader to get the exact height.

Comment: Yes It is working. But In every screen I need to set ZStack and your solution, which will be repetitive .

Comment: That is totally another question but don't worry and check out the updated answer ;)

Comment: How I could implement this in a TabView with different NavigationViews on each tab?

Answer (score 2):

### If someone's looking to color whole safe area or just parts of it, there's a simple solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color.accentColor 
            // Or any other color you like to color safe area with
            .ignoresSafeArea() // 1*
            <#Your View#>
        }
    }
}
```

1* You can choose which safe-area edges you want to ignore (`.all` is default). More about it here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid/ignoressafearea(_:edges:)

and Edge.Set which is a param of `.ignoresSafeArea()`:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/edge/set

##### Note

This won't work with bars (NavigationBar / Tabbar) because they have it's own top layer, but it works with custom and "regular" views that spread it's content to the safe area.